# Store and Restore Inherited Dockerfile USER setting

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm looking how can I store and restore the USER from an inherited docker image in a Dockerfile. My parent image for example specifies a default service and sets USER to serviceuser.

Now I have a depending image that inherits from the parent image, does some modifications as root, but want's to keep the docker image user to serviceuser.

I can do this manually:

parent Dockerfile:

```
from default
USER serviceuser
ENTRYPOINT ["some-service"]
```

other Dockerfile:

```
from parent
USER root
RUN apt-get install -y cool-stuff
USER serviceuser
```

However, this way when I change the user in parent I have to update all child images. Is there a way to dymaically do this in the child Dockerfile?

Other options I thought about are to use sudo in the child script or running the entrypoint as root (i.e. not setting USER) and doing the service user switch in the start script. But both have security implications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are author of parent image you can do this like this:

```
ENV serviceuser=foo
RUN useradd $serviceuser
USER $serviceuser
```

child image:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get install -y cool-stuff
USER $serviceuser
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that environment variables worked for USER. Even if I wasn't the author, I could simply introduce a layer in between that fixes this.

Comment: What is the answer if you're not the author of the parent image and USER wasn't stored in a ENV variable?

Answer (score 2):

The user specified in the inherited image can be obtained using `docker inspect`:

```
 % docker inspect <image name>
[
    {
        …
        "ContainerConfig": {
            …
            "User": "root",
```

`jq` can be used to parse out the value:

```
 % docker inspect <image name> | jq -r '.[].ContainerConfig.User'
```

That user can then be specified in the `USER` directive in the "child" Dockerfile.