# Switch USER for single RUN command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently I am facing the following challenge:
I am extending a base image, which sets a `USER` "safeuser" at the end. In my dependent image I try to make some changes to the filesystem of the baseimage, but since "safeuser" can't modify files from "root" I would need to change via `USER ROOT`, do my changes and then go back to `USER SAFEUSER`.

This approach does seem quite ugly, what if for example the baseimage changes the username from "safuser" to "othername"? Is there any way I can change the `USER` only during the build process, or `RUN` single commands as a different user without having to explicitly switch back to the original user? Or can I at least store some reference to the original `USER` during the build process somehow?

Comment: This may "seem quite ugly", but it's less ugly than adding extra moving parts like `sudo`.

Comment: I agree with Charles, and until a `SUDO RUN` command shows up in docker, you can just get the name of the "safeuser" user from an ENV variable set in the base image. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935511/store-and-restore-inherited-dockerfile-user-setting

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`sudo --user`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

```
root@machine:/home/user# whoami
root
root@machine:/home/user# sudo --user=user whoami
user
root@machine:/home/user# whoami
root
```

When used in a `Dockerfile`, it will look like the following:

```
# ...

RUN sudo --user=user mkdir /tmp/dir
RUN touch /tmp/dir/root_file
```

---

Edit: as @CharlesDuffy wrote below, doing this would require adding the `safeuser` to the sudoers of the build machine, which isn't ideal. I'd consider other (less elegant but more secure) options before choosing this one.

Comment: The OP is trying to move _from_ a less-privileged user _to_ a more-privileged user. `sudo` will let you _drop_ from root to a less-privileged user without authentication, but it requires configuration before it can be used to go in the other direction, as the OP intends to do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice it at first. I think this can be worked around by doing `USER user` at the beginning of the `Dockerfile`, then creating the `otheruser` explicitly in the `Dockerfile` as a root user, and then using `sudo --user` to use that user.

Comment: The thing is, the OP is letting the `USER` be set by a base image; they _don't want to need to know_ what that user account is named, so as to allow their extended code to avoid needing to change should the base image modify the username used for the account unprivileged operations are performed under.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Seems like that only helps us, as the only thing left to do is create `otheruser` and use it.

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps at all. The getting-to-root is not the problem; it's the getting _back_ to the base-image-specified original user that's the problem. Unless you propose something like having runtime code that inspects the image to figure out the account and then `sudo` over to whatever it finds? That's a lot uglier than what the OP is trying to get away from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy After using `sudo --user`, the shell will return to the image-specified user by itself. (If detecting the image-specified user is the issue, we can just store its name somewhere at the beginning of the `Dockerfile`, but I don't see why one would need to do this.)

Comment: _If_ you have `/etc/sudoers` configuration to _allow_ the base-image-specified account to use `sudo --user` to get to root. Setting up that configuration without _knowing_ the name of the account it needs to allow to su to root is... well, doable, I suppose, but finicky.

Comment: And if you set that up without being careful to tear it back down after, you'd be granting the unpriviliged user the ability to get to root whenever it likes, defeating the whole point of using an unprivileged account in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true. I guess there's no automagical solution. (Maybe Docker has a special flag which I'm unaware of that does this in an elegant manner.) Thanks for challenging my suggestion :)

Comment: Assuming ``sudo`` is installed in the container, what is unlikely in **most** of cases.

Comment: The solution is in this answer, which proposes storing the the safeuser username in an `ENV` variable in the base image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935511/store-and-restore-inherited-dockerfile-user-setting. Yes it's not an elegant single line solution, and does require switching to root and back, but it does decouple child images from the actual username.

Answer (score 0):

> Or can I at least store some reference to the original USER during the
> build process somehow?

Yes, with an `ENV` variable from the parent image, as discussed here: [Store and Restore Inherited Dockerfile USER setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935511/store-and-restore-inherited-dockerfile-user-setting)

From the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) documentation:

> A stage inherits any environment variables that were set using ENV by
> its parent stage or any ancestor. Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) for more on multi-staged
> builds.

Parent Image:

```
ENV unprivilegeduser=safeuser
RUN groupadd -r unprivileged && useradd --no-log-init -r -g unprivileged $unprivilegeduser
USER $unprivilegeduser
```

Dependent image:

```
#Switch to root for a single RUN command
USER root 
RUN doRootStuff
USER $unprivilegeduser
```

It needs three lines instead of a single, elegant "RUNAS" command that you wanted, but it is far cleaner than other alternatives like `sudo` and `docker inspect` ContainerConfig.User etc.
As per the [Dockerfile guidance](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/instructions/#user):

> Avoid installing or using sudo as it has unpredictable TTY and
> signal-forwarding behavior that can cause problems. If you absolutely
> need functionality similar to sudo, such as initializing the daemon as
> root but running it as non-root, consider using “[gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu)”.